# UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController: Why is tableView not populated?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I know how to use NSFetchedResultsController together with UITableViewController (There are tons of tutorials out there).

However, I need to use NSFetchedResultsController with a UITableView inside a normal UIViewController.

But my table cells are not populated despite no crash occurs neither an error is logged.

What am I missing?

Here is my code in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSError  *error;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    // Update to handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit (-1);  // Fail
}
    _tableView.dataSource = self;
    _tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

My NSFetchedResultsController:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(MRMedSafeAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest  *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest  alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription  *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                entityForName:@"Dokument" inManagedObjectContext:[cdh context]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor  *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"titel" ascending:YES];

    NSSortDescriptor  *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"dokument_art" ascending:YES];

    NSSortDescriptor  *sort3 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"erstellt_am" ascending:NO];

    NSSortDescriptor  *sort4 = [[NSSortDescriptor  alloc]
                            initWithKey:@"behandler" ascending:YES];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray  arrayWithObjects:sort3, sort4, sort1, sort2, nil]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    MRSingleton *singleton = [MRSingleton sharedMRSingleton];
    Patient *currentPatient = [singleton restoreCurrentPatient];
    NSPredicate *searchFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"patient = %@", currentPatient];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:searchFilter];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
    [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:cdh.context
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:@"Dokumente"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

And in my .h file:

```
@interface MRAlleDokumenteViewController : UIViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end
```

And, certainly, I have implemnted all the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    id  sectionInfo =
    [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (void)configureCell:(MRDokumenteTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    Dokument *dokument = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titelLabel.text = dokument.titel;
    cell.behandlerLabel.text = dokument.behandler.name;
    cell.behandlerLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.behandlerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
    cell.behandlerLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *stringFromDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dokument.erstellt_am];
    cell.erstelltAmLabel.text = stringFromDate;

    cell.dokumentArtLabel.text = dokument.dokument_art.name;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString  *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MRDokumenteTableViewCell *cell =
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Set up the cell...
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Basic step for this sort of question is to post NSLog in numberOfRowsInSection, log the tableview, it's datasource and delegate, and the count being returned.

Comment: so, fixed?  maybe just delete the question if so.